# How to filter the json data using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on asp.net mvc. I have a json response like,

```
[{"firstname":"xxx","lastname":"yyy","name":"zzz"},
{"firstname":"aaa","lastname":"bbb","name":"ccc"},
{"firstname":"zzz","lastname":"eee","name":"ddd"},
...]
```

Now i want to filter the above json response by name that startwith search criteria. I havebeen followed the following way,

```
var array=[];
array = jQuery.grep(jsondata, function (n,i) { return n.name.startsWith(searchstring); });
```

but i always get empty array. please guide me.

Comment: You would be better to filter the data server side, pass in your search query data as part of the JSON request.. maybe, I guess it depends on your UI requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) will help.

```
var data = $.parseJSON(<pass server json here>)[0], // 0 is used to match your example
    ret = [],
    rg = new RegExp('^' + search);

for (var i in data){
    if ( rg.test(data[i].name) ){ // '^' symbol is required.
        ret.push(data[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: starts with condition not working here. is there any other way for that?

Comment: actually i have a variable 'name' in that search string will be stored. `if(/^(search)/.test(data[i].name)` condition working for for me. how to place varible in the regular expression in place of serach

Comment: `RegExp` constructor accepts strings as an arguments. Updated the answer.